# Spring. Code works if setter is used and generates NullPointerException if change to directly assignment to field or when class constructor is used

Tags: java, spring, automated-tests

I've faced the next problem:

We have:

```
package com.project.e4.pages.v8;

import com.project.autotest.selenium.context.AbstractPage;
import com.project.autotest.selenium.context.IPage;
import com.project.e4.pages.v8.Components.ExamPlanButtons;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class TestPageClass extends AbstractPage<TestClass> {
    private ExamPlanButtons examPlanButtons;

    public TestPageClass setExamPlanButtons() {
        this.examPlanButtons = getComponent(ExamPlanButtons.class);
        return this;
    }
}
```

And this works pretty good for Selenium test:

```
getPage(StartPage.class, "")
    .clickSomeCoolButton() 
    .setExamPlanButtons();
```

`.clickSomeCoolButton()` returns `TestPageClass`:

```
@Report("click Some Cool Button")
public TestPageClass .clickSomeCoolButton() {
    waitForPresencSomeCoolButton.click();
    return redirectTo(TestPageClass.class);
}
```

`redirectTo()` implementation can be found below in the class `AbstractPageElement` description.

But as soon as I remove `setExamPlanButtons()` and change the assignment `getComponent()` to the field

```
private ExamPlanButtons examPlanButtons
```

directly:

```
@Component
public class TestPageClass extends AbstractPage<TestClass> {
    private ExamPlanButtons examPlanButtons = getComponent(ExamPlanButtons.class);
}
```

or to:

```
@Component
public class TestPageClass extends AbstractPage<TestClass> {
    private ExamPlanButtons examPlanButtons;

    public SomeTestClass() {
        this.examPlanButtons = getComponent(ExamPlanButtons.class);
    }
}
```

I got `NullPointerException` in the `getComponent()` method: `getRegistry()` returns `null`, because

```
@Autowired
private HelperRegistry registry;
```

is null.

**So the questions:**

- Why does this happen? (Is it related to the Spring? I'm not into Spring)
- Is it possible to get rid of `setExamPlanButtons();`?

Here is the `AbstractPageElement` class:

```
public abstract class AbstractPageElement<P extends AbstractPageElement> extends AbstractElementFinder implements IPageElement, ErrorSender {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @Autowired
    private HelperRegistry registry;

    protected final <E extends IComponent> E getComponent(final Class<E> target) {
        final E helper = getRegistry().getBean(target);
        helper.init(getDriver());
        return ReportAnnotationsWrapperCreator.getReportingProxy(target, helper);
    }

    protected final <E extends IPage> E redirectTo(final Class<E> target) {
        final E page = getHelper(target);
        page.handleRedirect();
        waitForPageToLoad();
        return page;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you said you're not into Spring: The Spring IoC needs a fully created instance of an object to inject the autowired beans in it. That means, that you can't access autowired fields inside of the constructor or initializer blocks, because Spring still had no chance to inject the "other" beans into it. If you change your assignment to `private ExamPlanButtons examPlanButtons = getComponent(ExamPlanButtons.class);`, then you're trying to initialize the `examPlanButtons` field during object construction and therefore in a moment where all autowired fields are still `null`.

Comment: Pass the registry into the dependent bean's constructor instead of using field injection.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Tom and chrylis.

Comment: @chrylis, could you clarify 'Pass the registry into the dependent bean's construct'. Should I create registry  Autowired
    private HelperRegistry registry; in the TestPageClass?

Comment: In `AbstractPageElement`, you have an autowired field; these are fragile and prone to break this way. Instead, have `protected AbstractPageElement(HelperRegistry registry)`.